# Query about Sequence containers in SSIS and using Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transactions

I have a SSIS package which contains 3 different Execute SQL tasks which are basically data stages, each stage is a stored procedure which is wrapped in a serialized transaction. I have wrapped all 3 into a sequence container, but im not sure whether the Transactions properties of the container would affect the fact that there are already transaction stored procedures in the Execute SQL Tasks. The default properties on the sequence container is:

- TransactionOption: Supported
- IsolationLevel: Serializable

Also would these settings cause a deadlock?

Thanks